# Find all $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ to satisfy $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)e^{(-t^2+2xt)}dt = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-transform

The problem is

> Find all $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ to satisfy $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)e^{(-t^2+2xt)}dt = 0$ a.e..

I'm studying convolution and Fourier transform in Folland chap 8. I faced this problem but I don't know at all. Someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The given equation is equivalent to $\int f(y)e^{-(y-x)^{2}}dy=0$ or $\int f(x-y)e^{-y^{2}}dy=0$. The convolution of $f$ with the exponential is therefore $0$ a.e.. Taking FT we see that $\hat {f} \hat {g}=0$ where $g(y)=e^{-y^{2}}$. $\hat {g}$ is never  $0$ and so we get $\hat {f}=0$ which implies $f=0$ a.e.
.

Comment: What about the $e^{x^2}$ outside the convolution?..because i pressume you added and substracted $x^2$ in the exponent.

Comment: $e^{x^{2}}$ comes out of the integral. Since this function is never $0$ you can cancel it. @MariosGretsas

Comment: Yes yes..i forgot  that there is an equation to be solved.. i just had in mind only the appropriate expression for the integral... my apologies...:) +1